# deleting a particular div with id attribute after clonning

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i have a requirement in which i want to delete a particular table row inside div, the structure is as follows

```
<div id='Dictionary0'>
  <div id='dept'>
    <table id ='books'>
      <tr id = 'row1'><td>..</td>
      <tr id  = 'row1'><td>..</td>
       ..
       ..
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
  </div>


<div id='Dictionary1'>
  <div id='dept'>
    <table id ='books'>
      <tr id = 'row1'><td>..</td>
      <tr id  = 'row1'><td>..</td>
       ..
       ..
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

i want to delete the rows with id row1 which are present inside Dictionary1 div , i used below command

```
$('#Dictionary1).find('#row1').remove();
```

this is not working. can anyone tell me what is the right way to achieve this

Comment: it's against the html rules that using same ID more than once for different elements, replace it with a class.

Comment: dude id should be unique

Comment: oops , i will keep in mind next time about unique ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An id should only be used once within a document. If you are planning on having the same identifier more than once, you should use classes.

```html
<div id='Dictionary0'>
  <div id='dept'>
    <table id ='books'>
      <tr class = 'row1'><td>..</td>
      <tr class  = 'row1'><td>..</td>
       ..
       ..
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
  </div>


<div id='Dictionary1'>
  <div id='dept'>
    <table  ='books'>
      <tr class = 'row1'><td>..</td>
      <tr class  = 'row1'><td>..</td>
       ..
       ..
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Using this approach you can then delete all the elements with the row1 class with the following code:

```
$('#Dictonary1 .row1').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a quote

```
$('#Dictionary1').find('#row1').remove();
```

Your #Dictionary1 was missing a quote

Answer (score 0):

you can remove elements like this

var element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

or 
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();